# How to print db value in ckeditor by using select option method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

Hi friends i am new to php and my doubt is i just create a select option using the mysql script in this select option it has five values every time i change the select option value the appropriate result will be displayed but the values are does not displayed in ckeditor textarea.Please help me to how to display the select option value using ckeditor.Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#parent").change(function() {
            var id=$("#parent").val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "try_ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#size").html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And Ajax Page Is

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    echo $_POST['id'];
    $erow=mysql_fetch_array($esql);
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="ck" cols="40" rows="10" ><?php echo  $erow['contact_details']; ?></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Drop Down list is Like

```
<select id="parent">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax response is a full HTML page. You just need to return something like:

```
<?php
$sizes = [10, 20, 30]; // get the data from DB.
foreach($sizes as $sz)
    echo "<option value='$sz'>$sz</option>";
?>
```

This will help you if '#size' is a drop-list element (i.e. HTML select).

Also, you can render JSON data from server then you can use JavaScript to populate the JSON data in the HTML element.

You need to read more about AJAX/JSON.

Comment: <select id="parent">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

Comment: above code is my drop down list sir.the drop down list id is parent.and #size is my result displaying id sir.

Comment: I added another answer, take a look

Answer (score 0):

I made this code to get data from server and populate them in the drop-list. It is just an example, you need to adapt it to be suitable for your case:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    $sizes = [10=>'Ten', 20=>'Twenty', 30=>'Thirty']; // get the data from DB.
    foreach($sizes as $sz)
        echo "<option value='$sz'>$sz</option>";
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="parent">
            <option value="">select</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#parent").change(function() {
            var id=$("#parent").val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "?ajax=1",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#parent").html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

I did not use JSON to make it simpler. I hope that will help :).
I get the data from the same page (url: "?ajax=1"), you can use what ever you want, like( url: "try_ajax.php").